# OS X Sierra: Increase maxfilesperproc

Tags: macos

I need to increase the number of allowed open files per process on OS X Sierra.

Currently, when I run

```
ulimit -n
```

The response is 2048.

None of the following techniques suggested on StackOverflow and other sites are working for me:

- [Creating Launch Daemons](https://blog.dekstroza.io/ulimit-shenanigans-on-osx-el-capitan/)
- Running `sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=10240`
- Adding the following lines to /etc/sysctl.conf 
  `kern.maxfiles=20480
  kern.maxfilesperproc=10240`
- Running `ulimit -n 10240`. Note that when I run `ulimit -n 512` I am able to successfully decrease the allowed limit but I can't seem to increase it.

My Launch Daemon for maxfiles is below.  The one for maxproc is similar.

```
localhost:LaunchDaemons jay$ ls -latr limit*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  540 Nov  8 11:10 limit.maxfiles.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  531 Nov  8 11:19 limit.maxproc.plist

localhost:LaunchDaemons jay$ cat limit.maxfiles.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">  
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>launchctl</string>
      <string>limit</string>
      <string>maxfiles</string>
      <string>64000</string>
      <string>524288</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Has anyone successfully increased the number of allowed open files per process on Sierra?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
# Check current limit
ulimit -n
256

# Raise limit
ulimit -S -n 4096

# Check again
ulimit -n
4096
```

Comment: When I try that, I get the following: 

`ulimit -S -n 4096`
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument

`sudo ulimit -S -n 4096`
/usr/bin/ulimit: line 4: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument

Comment: Sorry, not sure why mine works and yours doesn't. In `/etc/sysctl.conf` I only have `kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216`

Answer (score 0):

(not enough rep to comment) Yes, I was able to increase the open files limit after a lot of headaches and the [creating daemons solution](https://blog.dekstroza.io/ulimit-shenanigans-on-osx-el-capitan/) link. It finally stuck by setting the permissions correctly (it should be root:wheel) and rebooting.

This is the response on the machine's from `ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 64000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2048
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Note that I also used the same link to increase the max user processes. Increasing the open files limit stuck with setting the permissions on  `limit.maxfiles.plist` and loading the file with `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist`. But the changes to max user process (`limit.maxproc.plist`) did not work and required rebooting.

It's worth mentioning that while I was finally able to increase these limits, increasing them has not solved my issue.

**UPDATE**

I tried to set the open files limit on another machine running Sierra and encountered the same problems that the OP is having, specifically:

- running `ulimit -S -n 10241` encounters the error: `ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument` from Terminal
- I was able to lower the open files limit and raise it again, but not break the 10240 barrier without encountering the 'Invalid argument' error

I followed the instructions [in this answer Open files limit does not work as before in OSX Yosemite](https://superuser.com/a/1171026/763343) because it provides a sample of what should be in the `limit.maxfiles.plist` file. The soft limit is set at 64000 and the hard limit at 524288.

1. `sudo touch limit.maxfiles.plist` to create the file with the correct permissions (root:wheel).
2. With a text editor, I copied the example provided (in the answer above).
3. Then `launchctl limit maxfiles` reported `maxfiles    64000          524288` so everything is good! NO! `ulimit -n` still came back as `10240`
4. Then `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist` and `launchctl limit maxfiles` and `ulimit -n` and the result was the same as in step 3.

After restarting the computer, `launchctl limit maxfiles` and `ulimit -n` both return the new **soft** limit of 64000.

The open files limit can be lowered and raised, but not raised above the new **soft** limit of 64000. Raising the open files limit above 64000 requires editing the .plist file and restarting again.

`ulimit` and `launchctl` need to agree, it seems, and that only happens after restarting. There is a little more context about the two in [Difference between ulimit, launchctl, sysctl?](https://serverfault.com/a/746504), basically:

- `ulimit` is for the shell
- `sysctl` is for the OS
- `launchctl` is for MacOS and older MacOS (nee OS X) gets, the less it respects `sysctl` or treats its settings as temporary.

Comment: I tried the same thing before my original post.  My permissions are root: wheel, but no luck.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your .plist file to your post above?

Comment: Also make sure the .plist file is `0644`, per this tip: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/221988